# Deploying ReactJs Webpack on App Engine doesn’t load build files

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

Here's the app.yaml code to serve static build files to gcloud

```
runtime: nodejs16
entrypoint: yarn start
handlers: 
# Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: public/build/\1
  upload: public/build/(.*\.js) 

- url: /(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json
  static_files: public/build/\1
  upload: build/(.*\.json)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: public/build/\1
  upload: public/build/(.*\.css)

# Serve all static images with url ending with a image extension  
- url: /(.*\.png)
  mime_type: image/png
  static_files: public/build/images/\1
  upload: public/build/images/(.*\.png)
  expiration: "7d"  
# Catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html
```

This is my public build structure to deploy on gcloud

[image: Build Structure]

Getting 404 not found for the required static files.

[image: Error Logs]

These are the scripts commands:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "serve -s public",
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
```

Comment: Can you share how you reference the static files from within the HTML? Are you able to fetch your files when traveling to `https://<APP_ENGINE_URL>/file.extension`?

Comment: @ErnestoC I am not able to fetch files from the urls set.

Comment: Could you please add the dependencies and build tools you are using for this project? You could also try to provide a [minimal reproducible sample app](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Based on your directory structure and handlers, I have not encountered the same issue.